# How to upload a file with TYPO3 Fluid form.upload and pass it to Extbase controller

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-9.x

I am using the [form.upload](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Form/Upload.html) ViewHelper to upload a file.

```
<f:form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="list" name="import" object="{import}" method="POST">
    <f:form.upload name="file" property="file" />
    <f:form.submit value="Submit" />
</f:form>
```

The problem is accessing the file. The $import object contains a file name but the file does not exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My problem was, that the file was deleted already when it was handled. I redirected to another action in my controller action and this started a new request.

```
$this->redirect('list', $import);
```

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

(https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

How file is uploaded is not TYPO3 specific and can be handled differently, see link above.

- You should also set the temporary path accordingly, see link above.
- file types can be restricted with accept, e.g. `accept='text/csv'`

I am using this in a backend module. The following code works.

### Fluid

```
<f:form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="create" name="import" object="{import}" method="POST">
    <f:form.upload name="file" property="file" />
    <f:form.submit value="Submit" />
</f:form>
```

### Model class: Import.php

```
class Import extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{
    /** @var array */
    protected $file = [];

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $file
     * @return void
     */
    public function setFile(array $file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }
}
```

### Controller createAction()

```
/**
 * @param Import $import
 * @return void
 */
public function createAction(Import $import)
{
    $file = $import->getFile(); 
    if ($file) {
        $path = $file['tmp_name'];     
    }
    // ...
}
```

The action gets called with Import object containing a file property with correctly filled out metadata, e.g.

```
['name'] = myfile.csv
['type'] = 'text/csv'
['tmp_name'] = '/tmp/hpGLv1E' 
['error'] = 0
['size'] = 51550
```

Comment: You might also want to look at helhums upload example: https://github.com/helhum/upload_example
It deals with mapping uploads to models and also handels the case where a form has a validation error.

Comment: I moved from Helmuts implementation to using a similar approach as Sybille is using, with a slight improvement. I create a model for the upload array and am able to use extbase validators for checking filesize, filetype and upload errors for example. I find this approach a little cleaner then converting the uploaded file into a FileReference directly on upload as Helmut does it.

Comment: @Euli: Can you post an example about how you did exactly?